# Adding custom element to GPX wptType

Tags: gps, accelerometer, gpx

I'm looking for help, here is my problem. I'm developing software (in plain old C) for the custom device based on the STM32 microcontroller (it's not really relevant). I'm collecting data from GPS module and I also read raw data from the accelerometer. Now I want to log data to device storage but requirement states that I must use GPX format for logging GPS data. I was wondering how do I add the custom element to wptType, in my case acceleration data for every GPS waypoint. This is something I had in mind:

```
...
<wpt lat="45.804129" lon="15.930138">
    <acc_x>500</acc_x>
    <acc_y>400</acc_y>
    <acc_z>100</acc_z>
</wpt>
...
```

I have read about extension type, but I don't know how to implement it. I dont use XML in everyday life so this is relatively new for me.

Answer (score 0):

Okey, I managed to link my own parameters [schema](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Ivan47/test_repo/master/obu_qus.xsd). This schema "describes" some of my data beside GPS data.

This is my example .gpx [code](https://github.com/Ivan47/test_repo/blob/master/test.gpx). When I run my code through this [validator](http://xmlvalidator.new-studio.org/) I get "Validation successful". But I can't have more than one *extensions* blocks in  segment, also *extensions* block must be last element. I was hoping I could do something like [this](https://github.com/Ivan47/test_repo/blob/master/wish.gpx). Is there
some way to do this or alternative to this idea ?